# Jquery UI Datepicker close on pressing "OK" button

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

Ive set this button - closeText: "OK" ,

how to set up datepicker so it would not close when I pick day and close it only when "OK" button is pressed ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Try this out:- http://jsfiddle.net/adiioo7/L9N7K/4/

**JS:-**

```
jQuery(function ($) {
      $("#datepicker").datepicker({
          showButtonPanel: true,
          closeText: "Ok",
          onSelect:function(event){
              event.preventDefault();
          }
      });
  });
```

**HTML:-**

```
<input type="button" id="datepicker" value="Select a date" />
```

Comment: On selecting the date is not highlighting